# Sketch: Hide Bounding Box on Drag/Move

Tags: sketch-app

One of the things that I always loved about Sketch was that the bounding box of the selected item(s) would always hide when you dragged the element or moved it with your arrow keys.

[image]

It seems like with the 3.7 update, this functionality has changed and I can't figure out how to switch it back to the original setting.

Anyone know how to change this back to hide the handles/edges when moving something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to go back to the old behavior.

**But, you could do the following (until it becomes more trouble than it's worth):**

[image: View » Canvas » Show Selection Handles]

You can go into `System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts » App Shortcuts`, use the plus button to add `Sketch.app`, and create your own keyboard shortcut for `Show Selection Handles`

[image: Screenshot of App Shortcuts in the Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 System Preferences]